# C++ variadic templates: elegant way of listing all array elements depending on variadic template size

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Is there some elegant way to express a function call depending on some `n` which can be derived from template arguments

```
f(my_array[0], ... , my_array[n-1]);
```

inside a class template looking like this?:

```cpp
template <int... numbers>
class Abraham {
   static constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(numbers);
   some_type my_array[n];

   void foo(){
   //...
   f(my_array[0], ... , my_array[n-1]); // This line is no valid C++ Code. How can one achieve this in an elegant way?
   //...
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `numbers` used for, if you're only using the size of the parameter pack in this example?

Comment: @parktomatomi This is just a reduced version from the original code to get a minimal example. (The numbers will be used independently from the array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library has [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for this kind of thing

```cpp
template <size_t... Is>
void foo(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  f(my_array[Is]...);
}
void foo() {
  foo(std::make_index_sequence<n>{});
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zhbGdb